# Is it possible to check for invalid parameters when using parameter destructuring?

Tags: javascript

Suppose we want to pass named parameters to a function using parameter destructuring, so that we can have optional parameters with defaults, but we also want to detect invalid parameters and throw an exception (this is common with optional parameters in R, for example). Here's what I came up with to do this:

```
function myFunction(args) {
    var all_options=["foo","bar"];

    for (var prop in args){
        if(args.hasOwnProperty(prop) && all_options.indexOf(prop)<0){
            throw "Invalid argument: "+prop;
        }
    }

    //do stuff
}
```

and if you try to call the function with an invalid parameter it throws an error:

```
myFunction({foo:7,bar:8,foobar:9});
```

The problem with this is that `hasOwnProperty` is really more restrictive than what you want, rand if the user is using a prototype-based creational pattern for the arguments list, it will fail to catch invalid parameters. For example this won't throw an error:

```
var optionsPrototype={baar:8}
var myOptions=Object.create(optionsPrototype);
myOptions.foo=7;
myFunction(myOptions);
```

Here the user has accidentally misspelled the `bar` parameter name in the prototype, meaning that all of the subsequent calls to `myFunction` will silently use the default value for `bar` rather than the intended value `8`.

An alternative is to loop through all properties of `args`

```
function myFunction(args) {
    var all_options=["foo","bar"];

    for (var prop in args){
        if(all_options.indexOf(prop)<0){
            throw "Invalid argument: "+prop;
        }
    }

    //do stuff
}
```

A lot of tutorials say not to do this because javascript objects could have built-in properties other than the ones the user deliberately added, but this actually seems to work correctly when I test it.

So my question is can I go with `for (var prop in args)` without `hasOwnProperty` or are there edge cases where this will fail? Is there a better approach to validating arguments in parameter destructuring?

Comment: I would go with `Object.keys(args).every()` and not the for loop. In the end it is the same thing. Not sure what the issue is if they send too many items in the object. I would think you would be worries about it the other way around.

Comment: So you are just expecting `foo` and `bar` to be the members of `args`? And then throw an exception if they are members of the paremter object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in) operator instead:

> The in operator returns true if the specified property is in the
>   specified object or its prototype chain.

```js
function myFunction(args) {
    var all_options=["foo","bar"];

    for (var prop in args){
        if(prop in args && all_options.indexOf(prop)<0){
            throw "Invalid argument: "+prop;
        }
    }

    //do stuff
}

var optionsPrototype={baar:8}
var myOptions=Object.create(optionsPrototype);
myOptions.foo=7;
myFunction(myOptions);
```

Answer (score 0):

No, it does not seem to be possible to check for invalid parameters when using parameter destructuring. But it is possible to have optional parameters with defaults and detect invalid parameters by defining and calling a helper function like this:

```
function validateNumber(value) {
    if (typeof value !== 'number') throw new Error(`expected number but found "${value}" of type ${typeof value}`);
}
function validateOptionalParameters(parameters, validParameters) {
  for (const validParameter of validParameters) parameters[validParameter[0]] ??= validParameter[1];
  for (const parameter in parameters) {
    if (!validParameters.some(x => x[0] === parameter)) throw new Error(`invalid parameter: ${parameter}`);
  }
}
function totalCost(listPrice, options = {}) {
    validateOptionalParameters(options, [['tax', 0.25], ['discount', 0.3]]);
    validateNumber(listPrice); validateNumber(options.tax); validateNumber(options.discount);
    return (listPrice * (1.0 + options.tax) * (1.0 - options.discount)).toFixed(2);
}
console.log(totalCost(7)); // outputs 6.13
console.log(totalCost(7, {discount : 0})); // outputs 8.75
console.log(totalCost(7, {tax : 0, discount : 0})); // outputs 7.00
console.log(totalCost(7, {diskount : 0})); // throws Error
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).